# PHP strtotime returning the wrong result on calculation

Tags: php, html

I have the following which should cal days and hours until a match kicksoff/starts

```
    $time=$row['event_time'];
    $gameDate = $row['event_date'];

if($gameDate !== $lastDate){
        $calcDate= strtotime('Ymd',$gameDate,$time); //suspect problem is here
        var_dump($calcDate);
    $remaining = $calcDate - time();
        $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
        $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
    echo'<tr style="background-color:red;">';
        $lastDate = $gameDate;
                echo '<td style="background-color:#2980b9"><strong style="color:white">'.$gameDate.'</strong></td>';
```

However when I do a var_dump on `$calcDate` it only returns `bool false,false`

I have searched and tweaked and tried, hoping a more experienced php user can help me out here

*Assume date and time is 2015-05-17 08:00*

Comment: If you look at the manual, you will see that `strtotime` accepts at most 2 parameters, so yes, the problem is definitely there. What format are your date and time variables in the database in? Note that there you are probably better of storing a datetime value in the database itself.

Comment: You need to get the timestamp then pass it into the date function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php See example #2 or the user contributions.

Comment: Concatenate `$gameDate` and `$time`, and then use a format string that matches the combined format.

Comment: If the date and time is `2015-05-17 08:00` where the heck did you get `Ymd` from anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that row should be

```
$calcDate= strtotime($gameDate . " " . $time)
```

Please check the strtotime function manual for more information
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php